# Large files download fails with scrapy media_pipeline

Tags: scrapy

Some files are small but some exceed 300M. Those large fail to download. I'm using media_pipeline to download files. Output:

```
2016-07-08 18:11:22 [scrapy] WARNING: Received (208954047) bytes larger than download warn size (200000000).
```

This repeats many times. Then

```
Gave up retrying <GET http://pmd.foxsports.com.au/free/nogeoblock/2016/07/06/DVU_20160607_AFL_TONIGHT_201607061809/DVU_20160607_AFL_TONIGHT_201607061809_1596.mp4> (failed 3 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting http://pmd.foxsports.com.au/free/nogeoblock/2016/07/06/DVU_20160607_AFL_TONIGHT_201607061809/DVU_20160607_AFL_TONIGHT_201607061809_1596.mp4 took longer than 1800.0 seconds..
```

The timeout of 1800 s is extremely large. The 300M file download takes much less on my channel. However doesn't work. I know I can use some external lib/downloader.But if possible I want to do this by the framework means.

UPD: The exact scenario is the following:
0) The timeout shold be adjusted in settings.py (the timeout int "meta" request field doesn't work
1) The number of requests (6) files are passed through MediaPipeline.get_media_requests. Each request corresponds to a large file
2) Some files are downloaded fine
3) At some point further files are not downloaded. All remaining files fail with timeout. The framework retries downloading but with no avail. The timeout repeats the number of tries.
4) The same files could be downloaded fine with wget

Comment: Could it be the server blocking file downloads because you are hitting it too much intensively!?

Comment: I don't think so because other pages (smaller files) on the same server work fine and also because a ban would give a persisting reject, while here I can download them with another application or the same file may work on the next run.

Comment: I have seen a lot of cases where a ban is temporary. You say that "At some point further files are not downloaded. All remaining files fail with timeout. The framework retries downloading but with no avail. The timeout repeats the number of tries." That makes me think it is the server.